# How do you iterate through the member variables of an object?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection

I'm building a litle console app that involves a control hierarchy -- there are screens, and inside of screens you can compose controls together.

You can add controls to a screen by declaring member variables (which all inherit from AresControl). The control constructor takes a simple coordinate pair. It looks like this:

```vb
Public Class IntroScreen : Inherits AresScreen
    'Controls
    Private LabelSelect As New LabelControl(72, 0)
    Private Stats As New StatAreaControl(2, 2)
    Private Messages As New MessageAreaControl(22, 45) With {.ListeningForKeys = True}
```

Then, in the OnLoad event, you have to add all those controls to a collection so we can later iterate through them and do rendering and so on:

```vb
Public Sub Screen_Load() Handles MyBase.OnLoad
    MyBase.Controls.Add(LabelSelect)
    MyBase.Controls.Add(Stats)
    MyBase.Controls.Add(Messages)
End Sub
```

I would like to handle adding the controls to the collection in the base class automatically. Here's what I had in mind:

- Use reflection to iterate over the member variables
- Pull the ones that inherit from AresControl
- Add them to the collection

This would result in cleaner, convention-based code. But try as I might, I can't get it to work - I can walk the member variables of a type, but I need to walk the member variables of a live object.

This *is* possible, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using reflection. In the base class:

```vb
Public Sub DoLoad() 

        Dim controls = Me.GetType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic) _
             .Where(Function(f) f.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(GetType(AresControl))) _
             .Select(Function(f) f.GetValue(Me)).Cast(Of AresControl)()

        For Each c In controls
            Me.Controls.Add(c)
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1: Awesome, that got me to where I needed to go. I did an edit, and I went a little farther than I normally would have, hope you don't mind -- the code needed a few tweaks around the usage of GetType and some brackets were off. While I was at it I made it so it would work from a base class.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - add methods to that object to allow you to what you want and hide the details.  I think this is where encapsulation is your friend.